# Need to host the blog along with the main site in the same S3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, routes, jekyll, web-hosting

We have our main website (which is in React) served from a S3 bucket. Since we need to serve the blog (which is in jekyll) as well from the same domain (i.e. mainsite.com/blog) for SEO purposes we have included the files of blog in the same S3 bucket in a separate folder called blog. 
Now in the main site we have added an anchor tag to direct the user to blog.

```html
<a className="ml-nav-item" href="blog/index.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                   Blog
                 </a>
```

But instead of loading the index.html file in the blog folder it's loading the same index.html in the main site.
If we directly try to go to mainsite.com/blog, it loads without any problem. The problem is when trying to access the blog from the main site.
We have not used any routers.

How can I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In your question it self answer also there. because for blog/index.html there is no routing. when request reaches to S3 bucket level through your first page it will try to find the route. and it might not able to identify the blog/index.html, that's way it is redirecting to your mainsite index.html page. I guess you have given error page as your index.html. I mean while configuring the static web hosting you have given error page as index.html.

To fix this you can try to give the context path of blog/index.html href.

Comment: Are you saying me to add blog/index.html to error page? It did not work. :(

Comment: No if you add blog/index.html page as error page, if any error comes it will redirect there. i am saying add https://something.s3bucket/blog/index.html

Comment: Tried what you said. But didn't work. Is there any other work around?